# Xamarin forms editor push controls out of the scream

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, editor

I am a beginner in xamarin forms and I need to create a page that contains some labels and an editor. I want the default keyboard overlapping in android:  WindowSoftInputModeAdjust.Pan . When I writing in the editor and the rich max size that can display when the keyboard is up,it push the labels out of a scream. How can to disable the editor pushing the labels out of a scream but at the same time it can scroll the text inside ?

```
    <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="First"/>
        <Label Text="Second"/>
        <Label Text="Third"/>
        <Label Text="Fourth"/>
        <Label Text="Fifth"/>
        <Label Text="Sixth"/>
        <Editor HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="Red" />
    </StackLayout>
```

Comment: You can take a look at my answer now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can to disable the editor pushing the labels out of a scream but at the same time it can scroll the text inside ?

If you want to do this, I suggest you can not set Editor verticaloptions as FillAndExpand, otherwise it will always push control out of screen.

```
<StackLayout>
        <Label Text="First" />
        <Label Text="Second" />
        <Label Text="Third" />
        <Label Text="Fourth" />
        <Label Text="Fifth" />
        <Label Text="Sixth" />
        <ScrollView>
            <Editor
                x:Name="editor"
                BackgroundColor="Red"
                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />

        </ScrollView>

    </StackLayout>
```

**Update:**

> I need the editor to take all the space that is free under the label and not some default height or necessary height thnx.

You can call the following code in App() constructor.

```
 Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.On<Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.Android>().UseWindowSoftInputModeAdjust(WindowSoftInputModeAdjust.Resize);
```

And use Scrollview to scroll.

```
<StackLayout>
        <Label Text="First" />
        <Label Text="Second" />
        <Label Text="Third" />
        <Label Text="Fourth" />
        <Label Text="Fifth" />
        <Label Text="Sixth" />
        <ScrollView VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <Editor
                x:Name="editor"
                BackgroundColor="Red"
                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />

        </ScrollView>

    </StackLayout>
```

The screenshot like this:

[image]

Comment: I need the editor to take all the space that is free under the label and not some default height or necessary height thnx.

Comment: @psilos, please call `Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.On<Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.Android>().UseWindowSoftInputModeAdjust(WindowSoftInputModeAdjust.Resize);` in App constructor, can solved your issue, have you tried, please take a look my update.

Answer (score 0):

You must put your editor inside stacklayout

```
<StackLayout>
    <Label Text="First"/>
    <Label Text="Second"/>
    <Label Text="Third"/>
    <Label Text="Fourth"/>
    <Label Text="Fifth"/>
    <Label Text="Sixth"/>
    <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <Editor VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="Red" />
    </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: I tried your answer but the same issue.Stile pushes the labels out of the scream.

Comment: I tried this on Android and works fine. Are you experiencing this issue on iOS ?

Comment: It's not possible for me to trie it now for ios, but I coped exactly as you suggest.

Comment: I am afraid I misunderstood part of your question. To achieve this functionality you need to write a custom editor.

Answer (score 0):

Well in my understanding the reason this is happening is because of the `VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"`

When you read the document it says:

> The StartAndExpand, CenterAndExpand, EndAndExpand, and FillAndExpand values are used to define the alignment preference, and whether the view will occupy more space if available within the parent StackLayout.

What I would suggest is you remove it and try again!

For more information check : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/layout-options

### Update

Your code should look something like below :

```
<Grid> 
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
<Grid.RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
<Grid.RowDefinition Height="*"/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
 <StackLayout Grid.Row="0">....<StackLayout> //all the labels here
  <Editor Grid.Row="1" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" .../>
 </Grid>
```

### EDIT

I am using the following code and it works like a charm on Xamarin.Forms 4.2, I am also attaching a screenshot for you to see how it looks.

```
 <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackLayout Grid.Row="0">
            <Label Text="First" />
            <Label Text="Second" />
            <Label Text="Third" />
            <Label Text="Fourth" />
            <Label Text="Fifth" />
            <Label Text="Sixth" />
        </StackLayout>
        <Editor
            Grid.Row="1"
            AutoSize="Disabled"
            BackgroundColor="Red"
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
    </Grid>
```

[image: Editor]

Comment: I need the editor to take all the space that is free under the label and not some default height or necessary height thnx.

Comment: Okay in that case i would just change the layout a little updating the answer

Comment: Again the same with before.I remember that i have tried this apache

Comment: <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackLayout Grid.Row="0">
            <Label Text="First"/>
            <Label Text="Second"/>
            <Label Text="Third"/>
            <Label Text="Fourth"/>
            <Label Text="Fifth"/>
            <Label Text="Sixth"/>
        </StackLayout>
        <Editor Grid.Row="1" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="Red"/>
    </Grid>

Comment: G.hakim No my friend thnx!

Comment: I wasn't clear in my question. After you tapped 5-6 rows inside the editor, it will push the scream again up. I want after 5-6 rows the text to scroll inside the editor and not to push up the scream. Even you put 100 rows in the editor to scroll inside the visible part of the editor thnx.

Comment: Do you want an internal scroll in the editor? I mean the comment you just made is not making sense to me...

Comment: Yes, I want an internal scroll thnx.

Comment: Then you might wanna check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47047813/how-to-make-xamarin-forms-editor-scrollable-auto-resizable

Comment: @ G.hakim  thnk I will check and notify.